# Reference request: forcing diamond at every stationary subset of every regular cardinal

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I'm in search of a published proof that there is a (class) iteration that forces $\Diamond_\kappa(S)$ to hold for all regular uncountable $\kappa$ and all stationary $S \subseteq \kappa$.

It's OK if the citation assumes GCH.  Surprisingly, I've been unable to find such a thing.  Any suggestions?

Easton support iteration of adding Cohen sets at uncountable regular cardinals works, and the proof is routine to a set theorist.  But the intended audience of the paper I'm writing may not know iterated forcing, and I'd prefer to just give a citation.

Comment: Overkill, but can't you use Jensen coding to extend to a model L[x] for x a real?  That's probably citable... ;)

Comment: @ToddEisworth ha ha, yes that does answer the question as posed, but I really need it to be an Easton support iteration (so that I can cite another black box about progressively closed Easton support iterations).

Comment: I guess I can also just put in into a short appendix, so people who don't want to think about forcing iterations can happily never encounter it...

Comment: Maybe more helpful:  The construction of forcing GCH using class forcing is due to Jensen, in an abstract of the Notices that doesn't appear in Mathscinet.  See Exercise 15.15 in Jech's 3rd Millenium edition and references at end of his chapter. If you can find a reference for why the collapses he uses force diamond, you're done.

Comment: Thanks.  Diamond easily holds at successor cardinals after Jensen's forcing, but it's not obvious that it holds at inaccessibles.  A math fairy sent me an email with some abstract reasons this should be true for those type of iterations, but I'd prefer a more explicit adding of diamonds everywhere (i.e. at all regulars).  I think I'll just write a very brief appendix on it.

Comment: Assume no inaccessible cardinals exist. Problem solved.

Comment: @AsafKaragila that would definitely prevent what I'm trying to do!

Comment: "Like the fella once said, ain't that a kick in the head?"

Comment: while this isn't quite what you're looking for, you might be interested to take a look at the appendix of [Large cardinals need not be large in HOD](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.6335) and the references there to the works of Friedman and Brooke-Taylor on coding into the diamond pattern.